# Using asio::io_context::strand to serialize posted tasks

Tags: c++, synchronization, boost-asio, c++20, asio

I'm trying to synchronized the completion handlers using `strand` but I'm not getting the expected out. When I'm using `asio::post` without wrapping the completion handler in `strand` I get the correct output but it is not synchronized. When I wrap the completion handler in `strand`, I don't receive any output.

Here is the minimal reproducible example:

```cpp
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>

struct Task
{
    Task(int id, int wait_time) 
        : id_{id}
        , wait_time_{wait_time}
    {}

    void operator()()
    {
        std::cout << "Tast-" << id_ << " started. [" << std::this_thread::get_id() << "]" << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(wait_time_));
        std::cout << "Task-" << id_ << " finished after (" << wait_time_
                  << ") milliseconds. [" << std::this_thread::get_id() << "]" << std::endl;
    }
    int id_;
    int wait_time_;
};

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 engine(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution d(500, 2'000);

    asio::io_context ctx;
    asio::io_context::strand strand(ctx);

    std::vector<std::jthread> threads;
    auto count = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        threads.emplace_back([&]{ ctx.run(); });
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count * 2; ++i)
    {
        asio::post(Task(i + 1, d(engine)));
        // asio::post(strand.wrap(Task(i + 1, d(engine))));  /* THIS DOESN'T PRODUCE ANY OUTPUT */
    }
    ctx.run();
}
```

Output when using `asio::post(Task(i + 1, d(engine)));`

```
Tast-1 started. [17652]
Tast-7 started. [26096]
Tast-3 started. [56484]
Tast-8 started. [32000]
Tast-5 started. [Tast-6 started. [79448]
61340]Tast-2Tast-4 started. [55696]
 started. [84880]

Task-6 finished after (784) milliseconds. [79448]
Task-2 finished after (835) milliseconds. [84880]
Task-1 finished after (923) milliseconds. [17652]
Task-4 finished after (1281) milliseconds. [55696]
Task-3 finished after (1668) milliseconds. [56484]
Task-7 finished after (1763) milliseconds. [26096]
Task-8 finished after (1888) milliseconds. [32000]
Task-5 finished after (1982) milliseconds. [61340]
```

How to use `strand` to synchronize these completion handlers? I'm using `asio` standalone on Windows 10 and MSVC compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer identified your race condition.

Instead of manually managing the threads, only to then require a work-guard as well, I'd use the `asio::thread_pool` facility instead.

Also, don't use the deprecated strand nested typedef. Instead use a `strand<>` executor adaptor:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/823743f3d3124fa3)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

using Duration = std::chrono::steady_clock::duration;

struct Task {
    int      id_;
    Duration delay_;

    void operator()() const {
        static int tid_gen = 0;
        thread_local std::string const tid = "[" + std::to_string(++tid_gen) + "] ";

        std::cout << tid << "Task-" << id_ << " started" << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(delay_);
        std::cout << tid << "Task-" << id_ << " finished after " << delay_ / 1.ms << "ms" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    auto d = bind(std::uniform_int_distribution(500, 2'000), std::mt19937(std::random_device{}()));

    asio::thread_pool ctx(4);
    auto strand = make_strand(ctx);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 8; ++i)
        post(bind_executor(strand, Task{i, 1ms * d()}));

    ctx.join();
}
```

Prints e.g.

```
[1] Task-1 started
[1] Task-1 finished after 839ms
[1] Task-2 started
[1] Task-2 finished after 1674ms
[1] Task-3 started
[1] Task-3 finished after 1355ms
[1] Task-4 started
[1] Task-4 finished after 1368ms
[1] Task-5 started
[1] Task-5 finished after 1141ms
[1] Task-6 started
[1] Task-6 finished after 771ms
[1] Task-7 started
[1] Task-7 finished after 1445ms
[1] Task-8 started
[1] Task-8 finished after 881ms
```

[Mixing in some non-strand tasks (#9-12)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/535c53004f2894f8):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; ++i)
    post(bind_executor(strand, Task{i, 1ms * d()}));

for (int i = 9; i <= 12; ++i)
    post(ctx, Task{i, 1ms * d()});
```

Prints e.g.

```
[1] Task-9 started
[2] Task-1 started
[3] Task-10 started
[4] Task-11 started
[3] Task-10 finished after 984ms
[3] Task-12 started
[1] Task-9 finished after 1007ms
[2] Task-1 finished after 1417ms
[2] Task-2 started
[4] Task-11 finished after 1958ms
[2] Task-2 finished after 597ms
[2] Task-3 started
[3] Task-12 finished after 1659ms
[2] Task-3 finished after 1532ms
[2] Task-4 started
[2] Task-4 finished after 639ms
[2] Task-5 started
[2] Task-5 finished after 1576ms
[2] Task-6 started
[2] Task-6 finished after 1617ms
[2] Task-7 started
[2] Task-7 finished after 889ms
[2] Task-8 started
[2] Task-8 finished after 1451ms
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a race condition in the behavior of the `asio::io_context`.  If you call `io_context::run()` on it with no pending handlers to execute (and no `executor_work_guard` objects associated with it), the context simply goes into a stopped state, and returns.

So, what's happening in one case is that you're populating the context before any of the threads start executing `run()`, which means there is work to be performed, so it works as expected.  Or a thread reaches `run()` first, which because there is no work yet, the `io_context` enters the stopped state, and nothing is printed.

For a quick test, you can move the thread creation until after your for loop.  For a longer running work queue, I recommend looking at the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/executor_work_guard.html) for the work guard, which will prevent the context from stopping.

Comment: Yes, moving the thread creation after posting the handlers to `asio::post` wrapped in `strand` works fine. Thanks for clarification.